# Get client_id and service_email from google analytics

Tags: laravel-4, google-analytics

I developed web application where I need to allow users to embed their google analytics dashboard. In order to access analytics dashboard I need `client_id` and `service_email`.

Is there a way to grab `client_id` and `service_email` using `OAuth`, I don't want to force users to manually create `client_id` so they can integrate dashboard.

Just to mention I'm using `Laravel 4`.

Comment: `client_id` and `service_email` are not GA API properties. If you're talking about user authentication, that will be managed transparently by a Google Account (independent from Gmail) via `OAuth`.

Comment: @carlodurso I'm using this package: https://github.com/thujohn/analytics-l4 and it asks me for client_id and service_email. Now I'm confused how to sort this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get what's the issue here.

You actually have to set up a new project in https://console.developers.google.com. That is where you actually enable OAuth to Access Google Analytics API. The `client_id` and `service_email` you are referring to are actually the developer's one, which are accessible under **Project** > **API & auth** > **Credentials** in the *Dashboard*.

There's quite a lot to take in. I'll be available to clarify concepts for you.

---

*References:*

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/

Comment: I have this working already, I embeded analytics dashboard into my site. But I want to sell this website, so I need to make it easy for non-developers to connect their accounts with google analytics. In every example I found on internet, user has to provide client_id and service_email in order to make it work properly.

Comment: Easy for non developers? That's Google, not Apple! If you go through OAuth authentication, I don't see any shortcuts.